# implementing scrollable on ng-template

Tags: css, angular

I am using ng-template in my application. I have more information to display using it. I want to make it scrollable. when the screen size decreases. How can i implement it. please guide me.

HTML

```
<ng-template #myTemplate let-data class="myTemplate d-flex">
</ng-template>
```

scss

```
.myTemplate {
overflow: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

If you require horizontal scroll only, then use **overflow-x: auto**, or
If you require vertical scroll only, then use **overflow-y: auto**, or
If you require both use **overflow: auto**

```
<ng-template #myTemplate >
  <div class="myTemplate">hi</div>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>
```

.css

```
.myTemplate {
    overflow: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Note: If you use *overflow:scroll*, the scroll bar area will be visible always. If you use *overflow:auto* , scrollbar will be enabled only when scrollable area is available.